# .NET Core 3.1 executable doesnt start on certain machines

Tags: c#, publish, windows-server-2016, netcoreapp3.1

I'm trying to run my desktop app on my Windows Server 2016, but it doesn't start successfully.
My program framework is netcoreapp3.1, Debug Configuration.

Frameworks for runtime desktop apps and dev packs are installed on the machine.

The program shows in the task manager for 1 sec and it closes.
I don't think the issue is on my program, as all is working on my desktop.

What could I try more?

I also tried publishing the program with all the possible configurations and no luck at all.

Update:
Error inside Event Viewer

Description: A .NET Core application failed.
Application: program.exe
Path: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\v2\program.exe
Message: Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (program.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Autoupdater.NET.Official', version: '1.6.4'
path: 'lib/net45/AutoUpdater.NET.dll'

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer on the server.  Is there a corresponding error(s)?

Comment: @JayBuckman just found the error, could it be because on the output it tells me: 2>Package 'Autoupdater.NET.Official 1.6.4' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. ??